# Decode/Decrypt string using jQuery or JavaScript that was originally encoded in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, decode, encryption

I have a string that is encoded/encrypted using the following C# code:

```
public static string Encode(string text)
    {
        if (!Enabled)
            return text;

        return "~/Enc/" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));
    }
```

How can I decode/decrypt it on the client side and get the original string before it was encoded/encrypted?

I've already tried `atob(encodedString)` and it doesn't return the original value.

Comment: **[Did you find the below answer useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16553784/2377970)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always pass the client Url as a parameter in the viewmodel - ie.

```
 public sting AjaxUrl {get;set;}
```

etc. ,then in model in the javascript

```
 var link = '@Model.AjaxUrl'
```

(This may defeat the purpose of encryping the link though.)

Answer (score 1):

atob works fine if all you're doing is base-64 encoding something.

You're not, though.

atob isn't going to work because you wouldn't be getting the encoded string, you'd be getting ascii bytes of the string + the "~/Enc" text you're placing before it.